# About insertion and retrieval of data in Datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am new to PowerBuilder, I am learning basic pb right now. I am not yet good at coding I need a help from anyone regarding a module I am doing right now.

I have created an `employee` master table, and created two datawindows. 
One is tabular, the second is a free form for the same table. Now I have allocated these datawindows in a single window. One is front and other is back.

My requirement is:

- I want to insert the row in freeform view and reflect them back in tabular.
- During insertion it should check all scenarios like whether an empty row is there or not, if yes then it should set the focus to that empty row instead of inserting an empty row again.
- When double clicked on particular row in tabular, it should retrieve that record  in freeform view while hiding tabular datawindow.
- When  i right click and select tabular view when I am in freeform view, it should show me tabular view and vice versa.

Comment: It seems that your Shift key is broken, imagine not being able to type capital letters!

Comment: You have not started to write a single line of code. You should give it a try and come back to ask for specific problems. As is, the question a bit too broad.

Comment: I recommend that you start by testing and seeing the "Code Examples" that are installed with PowerBuilder, there you can find everything you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided requirements yet asked no question. A concise question will produce better answers.

**Here are concepts** that I suggest learning about before deciding on how to code.

- Connecting to database using **CONNECT** SQL statement
- Assign transaction (connection) to datawindow using **SetTransObject**
- Using **Retrieval Arguments** in a datawindow where clause
- Sharing via the **ShareData** function.
- Coding the **rowfocuschanged** event of your list datawindow object
- Coding the **ScrollToRow** or **Retrieve** functions when row changed on list
- Coding the **rightmousebuttonup** event to create menu instance (popup)
- Using **Visible** attribute or alternatively **Hide** or **Show** methods
- Using **SetRow** and/or **SetColumn** functions